# JsPDF in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron, jspdf

I build an simple app with electron that get the data from some `input` tag and insert this value in a pdf using `jsPDF`.

When I compile the app in local using the command `electron .` the app correctly works and when I click on the export bottom it opens a windows for chose where save the pdf.

Considering that the app in local correctly works I decised to package them. I use this command `electron-packager . FisrtApp --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --prune=true --out=release-builds"`. The packaging is a good end but when I try the final application it doesn't works. When I click on the export button the window for choose where save the file doesn't appear.

This is the code:

#### index.html

```
<div class="row m-top-30 m-bottom-30 text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id='customer' type='text' name='customer' class='form-control' placeholder='Customer'></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id='tag' type='text' name='tag' class='form-control' placeholder='Tag'></input>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id='pN' type='text' name='pN' class='form-control' placeholder='P.O.No.'></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row m-top-15">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="esporta" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Esporta</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### export.js

```
var base64Img = require('base64-img');
const JsPDF   = require('jspdf');

const LAYOUT    = base64Img.base64Sync('img/layout.png');

let customer, pN, tag;
var pdf = new JsPDF();

$(document).ready( () => {

    $(document).on("click","#esporta", () => {

        customer = $('#customer').val().trim();
        tag = $('#tag').val().trim();
        pN = $('#pN').val().trim();

        pdf.save(customer + '_' + tag + '.pdf');

    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the Chrome dev tools and debugging your code when running in the packaged exe? You can set breakpoints and inspect the state of your app that way at run time. Usually the dev tools are part of the default Electron app menu, which may be switched off, consult the Electron documentation for how to toggle dev tools.

Comment: @GrahamMc Yes, I try and when the button export was clicked generated this error `Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open`

Comment: I made a small similar example app. I am using Windows, so maybe that is different. I also package using electron-packager. The Save window opens correctly (without the error you mention) and the PDF saves as expected. Minimal repo on Github here: https://github.com/grahammcallister/stackoverflow-question-54495926 Is the error happening for sure in the line pdf.save ?

Comment: @GrahamMc Thank you vary much for the example! Using your simple demo, I found the error, I use the `base64-img` package for encoding the image and after the packaging it is not found. I move the dependencie of `base64-img` from `devDependencies` to `dependencies` in the `package.json` file end now this is the error: `no such file or directory, open 'assets/images/layout.png'`, but this is false because the file exist in those path

Comment: Glad you came right!